# EF Core 2.0 One to one - what's the deal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I don't think what I'm trying to do is crazy. I have a Person entity that will have one address. I don't want to have the `PersonId` as a property in my Address entity. When I try to save to the database though EF Core keeps giving me an error on not being able to insert NULL into the `PersonId` column on Address table.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set;}
    public Address Address { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Street { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}
```

Database Tables:

Person: Id, Name

Address: Id, Street, PersonId

Or do I need to have reference navigation properties at both sides, which seems really silly to have to do.

Comment: You need addressId in your person table with reference to key in Address table

Comment: If the relationship is one-to-one, why not just merge both tables into one table? is the table too big?

Comment: in the person table, is addressid non nullable, and likewise for personid in the address table? And are ids created by the database, such as identity columns?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 1:1 person:address you can use Value object as well. Its awesome.

Your main object registered in your DbContext for EF

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }


public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; private set;}
  public string Name { get; private set;}
  public Address address { get; private set;}

  // .. constructor etc
}
```

And your Address object as Value object with attribute `[Owned]`

```
[Owned]    
public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; private set;}
   public string Street { get; private set;}
}
```

and then set mapping in DbContext `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(o => o.Address);
```

EF will generate your value object into Person table but in your application you will have two objects.

[owned-entities article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Comment: This is not the expected solution as he said that there will have `Person` and `Address` tables in the database.

Answer (score 1):

that should do it:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}

    public string Name { get; private set;}

    public int AddressId { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address address { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}

    public string Street { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}
```

Comment: This doesn't map a one-to-one relationship.  This maps a many-to-one relationship from person to address.  There's nothing here that prevents many people from sharing the same address.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to have the `PersonId` as a property in my Address entity.

Then how will you map `Address` entity to `Person` entity? How will it become an one-to-one relationship?

If you want to maintain one-to-one relationship between `Person` and `Address` then you have to keep either `PersonId` to `Address` Table or `AddressId` to `Person` table as foreign key.

As `Person` entity is the parent entity and `Address` is the dependent entity, its good to keep `PersonId` to `Address` table as foreign key. Moreover as Person will have one address at a time, you can also make the `PersonId` as the primary key of the `Address` table too as follows which will ensure that `Person` will have one `Address` record at a time:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set;}

    public Address Address { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}

public class Address
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; private set;}
    public string Street { get; private set;}

    public Person Person {get; set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}
```

You can also achieve the same thing using `Owned Entity` as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set;}

    public Address Address { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}

[Owned]
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; private set;}

    // .. constructor etc
}
```

Then in the `DbContext`

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // In case of Owned Entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(p => p.Address, a =>
        {
            a.ToTable("Address");
            a.Property(p => p.Street).HasColumnName("Street");
        });
    }
}
```

Another solution is too keep the `Address` information in the person table too. For this just remove `a.ToTable("Address");` from entity configuration. So the configuration will look like:

```
// In case of Owned Entity
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(p => p.Address, a =>
{
     a.Property(p => p.Street).HasColumnName("Street");
});
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to have the foreign key property in Address is that I'm doing DDD and don't want to muck up the domain model with things just to make EF work.  I thought with Shadow Properties upon saving EF would save the "PersonId" value into the Address table.

Comment: Then you have to store Address information in the Person table too. Shall I provide solution for that too?

Comment: Sure, thanks.  Maybe the reason it doesn't work as I want is because from a database perspective it looks like a one to many (Person as parent table, Address as child table which holds the FK... therefore Person could technically have 0-n Addresses.) Maybe because of this EF requires slightly different things.

Comment: No! If you use this `[Key,ForeignKey("Person")]` or the second solution(`Uisng Owned Entity`) then it will always be 0-1 address, not 0-n address because here `PersonId` is the primary key of `Address` table and primary key cannot be duplicated!

Comment: Please! check my answer. I have updated it.in the last solution `Address` information will be stored in the Person table too  and there will be no `Address` in database.

Comment: so using Owned Entities is probably what I want to do here then, so I don't need referential properties hanging out in my model just for db mapping purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184924/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-user1560457).

Comment: Yes! You can go with Owned entity!

Answer (score 1):

Neither explicit FK property nor navigation property is mandatory in EF Core for defining a relationship.

Just by convention the model with only reference navigation property is mapped to one-to-many optional relationship. So without fluent configuration, the EF Core implied relationship from your model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set;}
    public Address Address { get; private set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Street { get; private set;}
}
```

is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("AddressId")
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

while your requirement is one-to-one with `PersonId` FK column in `Address` table.

Since EF Core conventional assumption apparently is wrong for your case, you need to override it with fluent configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Address>("PersonId")
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Note the explicit generic type argument of `HasForeignKey`. It's used to indicate which of the two entities is the dependent, hence contains FK - `Address` is this case. The similar method for one-to-many relationships doesn't need that because the "one side" is always the principal and "many side" is the dependent. For one-to-one `HasOne` / `WithOne` are not enough to determine the principal and dependent, so the generic type argument of `HasForeignKey` / `HasPrincipal` method serves this additional purpose.

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).